# Track all function calls at run-time

Tags: c++, c, windows, internals

Is there some way to track every single function call happening in my app at run-time? So even if I were to open my app in a debugger and add a call instruction, I could catch that too?

One way I could think of is putting a page guard on the .text portion of my program and inside a vectored exception handler I check if the next instruction is a call instruction and set a single step flag if so, but I am not sure if I could even do that without either breaking my program or just making it incredibly slow with all the virtualprotect calls.

So is my idea somehow do-able or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Profiling usually does something like that. What is the real problem you need to solve? Why do you need something like this?

Comment: It's not to solve an issue, I'm just trying to see if I could protect a program against hooks or other exploits by making sure the calls happening are approved by my program (kind of like control flow guard)

Comment: Dig through this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.4.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html specifically `-finstrument-functions`. But this won't help you to protect against hooks, as it is instrumenting in compile-time.

Comment: Look at CFI and other ROP/JOP/COP type prevention.  It's quite a rabbit hole :)

Comment: You might be able to write a script driving a debugger like gdb to step through the code and a second script to filter the output for calls.

Comment: yes. its called logger! use logger and log all functions and log all the data that you need into a text file.

Comment: Even if you manage to record all function calls and to include a check that only the expected sequence is used, what should a hacker prevent to not only patch or inject a hook and at the same time manipulate your check? -- After nearly 40 years of programming I think there is no way to protect software against manipulation purely with software.